# Closest Google Font to Amazon's new "Amazon Ember" font?

Tags: fonts, font-identification, font-recommendation, font-design

Amazon in the UK has implemented a new font called "Amazon Ember".
A [product page](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B01HRLIAT2/?tag=ho01f-21&tag=uk--21) shows the squarish font, which has two-storey *a*, single-bowl *g* and flat top to the digit *3*:[image: Screenshot from Amazon UK site]

My amateur eye can't seem to match the closest font on Google Fonts. https://fonts.google.com/

What is the closest Google font to this? I personally think, Lato?

Also, is there a way to download and use Amazon Ember on a website or app?

Comment: What do those bags have to do with Amazon’s font? And where is the font you’re talking about even used? I just see a page full of text set in Helvetica.

Comment: merch89 can you edit your question and add a screenshot showing the font you're talking about? If that link changes or Amazon changes their font your question will be useless and impossible to answer.

Comment: It has already changed, it seems they reverted to Arial.

Comment: If it had changed, it's changed back. I took a screenshot as it appears today. CSS still shows "Amazon Ember".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ember is a typeface that was commissioned by Amazon for use on the Kindle Oasis. Here's a sample:

[image]

---

As far as a close Google font, I'd say you're on the right track with [Lato](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Lato). Another alternative would be [Roboto](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto). Both are nice clean alternatives to the Amazon font:

[image]

---

[image]

Answer (score 11):

I have found a link to download the Amazon Ember font and all weights on the Amazon Developer website. The file download also includes the Bookerly typeface.

https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/avs-devcomm/QuickStart-Guide_Assets.zip

If this doesn't work then go to this page and click on the "Out of box experience recommendations" and the download link is in the first paragraph of text. Labeled "HERE"

https://developer.amazon.com/docs/alexa-voice-service/marketing-and-branding-guidelines.html#oboe

Comment: Wow, great find. Any idea what the license conditions are of it?

Comment: @HashimAziz See [my answer below](/a/145093/111570).

Answer (score 8):

I'd actually go with [PT Sans](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/PT+Sans), which seems to share quite a few characteristics, narrow, curved lowercase l, monocameral g, high middle strokes on the M.

[image: PT Sans]

If you need more weights, then I'd go for [Source Sans](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Source+Sans+Pro), which does not come as close but has a LOT of weights and widths.

Answer (score 6):

I'd say **Ubuntu**.

Comparison:

[image]

Main differences: Arm of the small **t** and the descenders of **d**'s and **a**'s

Comment: When Amazon Ember was first deployed, I thought they had switched their site to the Ubuntu font. I think this is the closest indeed.

Answer (score 3):

Working with this for a while, I just found [Assistant](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Assistant) is a spooky close second.

[image]

Comment: I just wish it had true italics, but it's nice find whatsoever.

Answer (score 2):

Amazon now provides their complete font set on Amazon Alexa Design Guides, the [Typography](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/alexa/branding/echo-guidelines/identity-guidelines/typography) page. There's a big blue **Download** button on the right of the page, which leads to [this link](https://m.media-amazon.com/images/G/01/mobile-apps/dex/alexa/branding/Amazon_Typefaces_Complete_Font_Set_Mar2020.zip) (it's a direct download). The ZIP package contains all Amazon Fonts, including Amazon Ember, Amazon Ember Display and Bookerly (a serif font), with both desktop format (TrueType TTF) and web formats (Embedded OpenType EOT, WOFF and WOFF2) packaged.

#### Copyrighting

A file named `Amazon Ember Licensing Guidelines.pdf` is also bundled in the ZIP package with some directives that I don't fully understand. Relevant parts are quoted below (emphasis mine):

> Amazon has created a limited library of typefaces for use across all products, interfaces, and websites. **These fonts are fully owned by Amazon, making their usage free to all internal product teams.** Fonts other than those listed below, such as Palatino, Baskerville, Caecillia, and others are licensed from their respective rights holders (generally Monotype Corporation). To use these other fonts with your product you must secure a license that covers the distribution and display of the desired fonts.
>
> All of these fonts were developed under contract for Amazon - as a result Amazon owns them fully outright. **To include these designs in your work there are no licenses payments, no royalties, no copyright or attribution notices required.** The font itself carries the proper ownership and copyright information in the header metadata of the font and Amazon does not require any additional attribution or protections when using the font.

The text *may* suggest that anyone (within or outside Amazon.com, Inc) may use the fonts anywhere but I couldn't secure this assumption, so **use at your own discretion**.

Comment: That page is specifically for Amazon developers, so I would say it’s about 99.9% certain that this wording refers exclusively to use by Amazon developers in products within the Amazon universe.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Yep that my first impression too. The website seems to target developers *for* the Amazon ecosystem, and that particular page is for developing for Alexa, so yeah you're basically right.

Answer (score -1):

I think Sofia Pro Semi Bold or within the Sofia Pro family.

[image]